# Magento 2: Issue while Delete Invoice Programmatically

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, delete, magento2.1.5

I have below code

```
$orderId = 1;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->order = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

$invoices = $this->order->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    //delete all invoice items
    $items = $invoice->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item->delete();
    }
    //delete invoice
    $invoice->delete(); // ISSUE
}
```

It deletes the Invoiced Item, but not deleting invoice from `sales_invoice` Table. It gives below error

```
a:4:{i:0;s:46:"Delete operation is forbidden for current area";i:1;s:9802:"#0 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb.php(431): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->beforeDelete()
#1 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Model\AbstractModel.php(816): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->delete(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
#2 D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index.php(93): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->delete()
#3 D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index.php(68): Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index->ballot()
#4 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(102): Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index->execute()
#5 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#7 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Custom\Module...', 'dispatch', Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#8 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Custom\Module...', 'dispatch', Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#11 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Action\Plugin\Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Custom\Module...', 'dispatch', Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#14 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Custom\Module...', 'dispatch', Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#17 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Custom\Module...', 'dispatch', Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#20 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(112): Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 D:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(26): Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#23 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Custom\ModuleController\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#27 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#30 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#33 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#36 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 D:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#39 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 D:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#42 {main}";s:3:"url";s:29:"/sg-mint-local/magento/ballot";s:11:"script_name";s:32:"/sg-mint-local/magento/index.php";}
```

Comment: try this `$invoice->getResource()->delete();`

Answer (score 0):

load the invoice model fully

> $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
>   $invoice =
>   $_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice')->load(
>   $invoice->getId()); $invoice->delete();

Comment: It gives error `Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::delete() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel, none given`

Comment: How to get Invoice Id on basis of Order?

Comment: It gives `Delete operation is forbidden for current area`